# Could there be an auto filter for answers that are "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, not-an-answer

When I review answers that are flagged as "Not An Answer", it is surprisingly often the case that the answer starts with **"I have the same problem"** or something like that or – what is also a good indicator – the 'answer' has more question marks in it than the actual question

I noticed that are auto-filters for "excessively long" questions. Would it be a good idea to implement such an auto-filter for answer-is-not-an-answer suspects?

Comment: What about "I have the same problem and this is how I solved it....".  I think you'll get just as many false positives as valid bad questions.

Comment: Triggering flags based on keywords or a RegEx expression is usually more trouble than it is worth because either someone will find a way around it or it will cause too many false positives

Comment: Computers are idiots, and they are very very fast at it. That's the main problem with automatic decisions about worthy / unworthy content. [Unless you are looking for a cat](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/26/technology/in-a-big-network-of-computers-evidence-of-machine-learning.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0). Automatic cat recognition in multimedia is developed (with neural networks as far as I remember) and pretty stable. Too bad it's mostly useless the way it is now, and requires 16,000 computer processors.

Comment: I have the same problem... and what I did was...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's any reliable way to filter these out automatically.  As [psubsee2003](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199812/could-there-be-an-auto-filter-for-answers-that-are-not-an-answer#comment635162_199812) mentioned in the comments, any phrase that looks like a question (e.g. "I have the same problem...") can be followed by an answer.  A lot of times people will even quote part of the question and answer it directly. We already get a lot of false flags from *people* on answers of the form "I have the same problem and this is how I solved it...." so we have to be careful not to delete actual answers.  I think an automated flag on question-like phrases in answers would generate a lot more false positives.